# What icon represents "recommendation"?

Tags: icon, interface-design, resource-recommendations, symbols, user-experience

Building a notification system in an app. Each type of notification has it's own icon.

Within the app a concept of "Recommendations" is being developed. Person A can recommend an item to person B.

What icon could be used to represent this notification? The item could be anything, but is most likely a product to buy.

Cannot use a thumbs up as this is used for the concept of "likes".

Is there already an standard icon for this concept of recommendations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Subjective, since we don't know the overall context, but "recommending" a product generally involves sharing that particular product with a contact.

In the wording/notifications/etc, you can call it "recommend", but in fact it is a share from person A to person B. In which case you can go with a generic share/arrow icon, obviously adapted to your specific style/branding/UI:

- https://thenounproject.com/icon/share-2367230/
- https://thenounproject.com/icon/share-1867708/
- https://thenounproject.com/icon/share-3772168/
- https://thenounproject.com/icon/reference-2518880/
- https://thenounproject.com/icon/send-1425488/
- https://thenounproject.com/icon/share-5627736/
- https://thenounproject.com/icon/share-1247190/

Comment: Thanks, it was that re-framing my thinking that I needed. Couldn't get out of the rut of thinking of "recommending", not of the broader umbrella of sharing. Suitable icon found, cheers.